# Foundation - do not want to hide right button of navbar

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

On wider screens my login button is visible, but on smaller screens it is hidden.

[image]
[image]

JSBIN http://jsbin.com/nowubuseqeza/1/edit?html,js,output

Relevant code:

```
<div class="top-bar" data-topbar="" style="background:#074e68">
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="/"><img class="left" src="images/pluslogo.png" style="margin:2px 1em;height:40px;width:40px" alt="Pacific Medical Training"> Pacific Medical Training</a></h1>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="top-bar-section">
        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="/login/">Login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to have this visible in all circumstances? Otherwise my users cannot login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nowubuseqeza/4/)

```
<div class="top-bar" data-topbar="" style="background:#074e68">
    <div class="top-bar-section right">
        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right show-for-small">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="/login/">Login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="/"><img class="left" src="images/pluslogo.png" style="margin:2px 1em;height:40px;width:40px" alt="Pacific Medical Training"> Pacific Medical Training</a></h1>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="top-bar-section">
        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="/login/">Login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, I see the second button for small screen media type, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the smaller screen, a number of css properties are changing for the title-area and the links in the top-bar. If you add the following, it should bring the login button back on small screens:

```
//Only use it for screens under 40.063em, using the media query
@media only screen and (max-width: 40.063em) {
  .top-bar .name h1 a {
    width: auto;
  }
  .top-bar-section ul {
    width: auto;
  }
  .top-bar-section ul li.active > a {
    padding: 0px 15px;
    line-height: 45px;
  }
  .top-bar .title-area {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

However, it may need a bit more refinement for very small screens where the "Pacific Medical Training" takes up the whole top-bar and pushes the login button down